# if IsDbNull not working when insert into DataTable vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datatable

Sorry I posted the code with mistake and now changed to the correct one.
I am really confused here, what ever i do the empty datareader will be added to datatable and will shown in DataGridView!, whats wrong with my code??:

```
 constring2()
        con2.Close()
        Try
            Dim dt As New DataTable
            dt.Columns.Add("pno")
            dt.Columns.Add("date")
            dt.Columns.Add("atttime", GetType(String))
            con2.Open()
            Dim sq As String = "select * from OLDLOG"
            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(sq, con2)
            Dim dr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader

            While dr.Read
                Dim ss As Date = dr("DATE")
                Dim xy3 As String
                xy3 = ss.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")
                If Not IsDBNull(dr("IN_")) Then
                    dt.Rows.Add(dr("BADGENO"), xy3, dr("IN_"))
                End If
                If Not IsDBNull(dr("OUT_")) Then
                    dt.Rows.Add(dr("BADGENO"), xy3, dr("OUT_"))
                End If

            End While
            dr.Close()
            con.Close()
            DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Finally
            con.Close()
        End Try
```

and this the result of my code!,
[image]
 what i want is if dr("IN_") or dr("OUT_") are empty the data will not be in datatable! please any idea? thanks

Comment: Read your code. Your first condition is `If Not IsDBNull(dr("IN_")) Then` but the second is `If Not IsDBNull(dr("OUT_")) = False Then`; that's a double-negative.

Comment: you are adding a row if one or the other is present

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give this a try and see how it works out for you... The `IsDBNull` function indicates whether an expression evaluates to the System.DBNull class and in your case it doesn't. On the other hand, `DBNull.Value` represents a nonexistent value; for example: a column in a row might be 'Null'.

*Also if the value ISNOT NULL and just empty it will pass these conditions.

```
 'Check if it's not NULL and it's not empty...
 If dr("IN_") IsNot DBNull.Value AndAlso CStr(dr("IN_")).Trim <> "" Then
   dt.Rows.Add(dr("BADGENO"), xy3, dr("IN_"))
 End If
 If dr("OUT_") IsNot DBNull.Value AndAlso CStr(dr("OUT_")).Trim <> "" Then
   dt.Rows.Add(dr("BADGENO"), xy3, dr("OUT_"))
 End If
```

Comment: Is it actually NULL or just empty and what's the DataType?

Comment: to be honest i didn't know that there is difference between null and empty. so how i know if it empty or null?

Comment: @OsamaGadour yes there's a big difference between the types. If you want to check if it's empty you could use the trim function... Or best yet, handle this all in your query itself and return the data how you want it...

Comment: From the sound's of it, it's probably empty and not null if it's still getting added.

Comment: @436f6465786572 `If dr("IN_") IsNot DBNull.Value AndAlso (Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dr("IN_")) Then ..."`. [String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @436f6465786572 My apologies: I meant to reply to the OP, not you, regarding "so how i know if it empty or null."

Comment: @436f6465786572  Big Thank bro, it was empty, i just used (If Not Trim(dr(IN_)) ="") and it worked, thanks again.

Comment: Exactly I started to think it wasn't null.. I had that in my updated answer as well...

Comment: @AndrewMorton I see, it happens... wasn't for sure if you were talking to me. There's also String.IsNullOrEmpty method which would work as well...

Comment: @OsamaGadour the consensus is if any of the answer's provided has helped please mark as accepted and vote.

Answer (score 0):

How about not retrieving the unwanted values from the database?

```
Dim sq As String = "SELECT * FROM OLDLOG WHERE [IN_] IS NOT NULL AND [OUT_] IS NOT NULL"
```

Comment: Im not shure this will work cuz in some rows the [IN_] is empty and [OUT_] is not, so ur query will read only when IN_ and OUT_ are not empty.

Comment: @OsamaGadour You seem to be confusing the English version of "and" with the usual programming version of `And`.

Comment: I've tried ur query and it gives me the same results with the empty cells